# is there a way to find the scope of an object?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a flutter plugin that instantiate objects in the dart code mapping other objects at the native side. I want to preserve memory by deleting objects at native code once their scope ends at the dart code.

Comment: How do you want to remove them from memory?

Comment: they are created in a static list that is kept during the lifetime of the app. I want to remove them from the list once their scope ends in the dart code.

Comment: How does their scope end early? You just said that the list persits until the app dies.

Comment: here how it goes: you, as a user of the plugin, can instantiate an object, e.g. in a function that has a limited scope. this object adds a new one to the list at the native code mapping to it by an ID. What i want is, if the scope of the object ends in dart, remove the object from the list in the native code. the list is persists until the app dies but this list is at the native side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with the flutter framework managing your resources you could just wrap them within a State Object. 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html
The framework calls *dispose()* once the referring Stateful widget is permanently removed from the widget tree.

(1) Simple to implement - no control

```
class ResourceManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ResourceManagerState();
}

class ResourceManagerState extends State<ResourceManager>{
  Resource referenceToResource;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // create/open your unmanaged resource here
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // close/destroy your resource here
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidgetThatUsesTheResource();
  }
}
```

Things do get more complicated if you need to have more control over the resource. The garbage collector does not release the resource exactly when the Widget goes out of scope but only sometime later (or maybe only when the application is terminated)

Alternatively you could manage your resource using the *didChangeDependencies* and *deactivate* methods of the State object. I'd expect these to be called more reliably  and closer in time to the actual scope change of the resource:

(2) still simple - slightly more control

```
class ResourceManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ResourceManagerState();
}

class ResourceManagerState extends State<ResourceManager>{
  Resource referenceToResource;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if(referenceToResource = null) {
      // open/create resource here
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // close/destroy your resource here
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidgetThatUsesTheResource();
  }
}
```

(3) requires some work - even more control

If you need to reliably manage a limited number of resources you might have a look at the pool plugin for Flutter:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pool